# Difference between XLS and XSLFO

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, xsl-fo, aspose.pdf

What's the difference between XLS and XSLFO? It's a bit confusing.  I want to convert an XLS file to PDF but aspose.pdf documentation doesn't have a XLS-PDF guide (using aspose.pdf). They only have XSLFO to PDF. And I'm wondering if the code in XSLFO to PDF will still be applied in converting XLS to PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XLS** is either a typo for **XSL** or a reference to Microsoft's [Excel](https://products.office.com/en-us/excel) spreadsheet [format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats).

**XSL** [refers](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) to a family of W3C recommendations related to XML transformation and presentation:

- **[XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)**: A language for transforming XML documents.
- **[XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)**: A language for addressing parts of an XML document.
- **[XSL-FO](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/)**: An XML vocabulary for specifying formatting.

Comment: Thanks you very much :)